# HP Elite 8300 SFF - Change Bios Boot Order WMI

Tags: vbscript, wmi, boot, bios

I use this vbscript to change Bios Boot Order settings from Windows:

```
function ErrCode(oReturn)
    Dim strReturn
    Select Case oReturn
        Case 0 strReturn = "Success"
        Case 1 strReturn = "Not Supported"
        Case 2 strReturn = "Unspecified Error"
        Case 3 strReturn = "Timeout"
        Case 4 strReturn = "Failed"
        Case 5 strReturn = "Invalid Parameter"
        Case 6 strReturn = "Access Denied"
        Case Else strReturn = "..."
    End Select
      ErrCode= strReturn
    end function

    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationlevel=impersonat​e}//./root/HP/InstrumentedBIOS")
    Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("select * from HP_BIOSSettingInterface",,48)

    For each objItem in colItems
    objItem.SetBiosSetting oReturn, "Boot Order", "Network Controller,Hard Drive,ATAPI CD-ROM Drive"  ,"<kbd/>"
    if oReturn then
        wscript.echo "Boot Order" & " Can not be set, Error="  & ErrCode(oReturn)
        wscript.quit(oReturn )
    end if
Next
```

It gives me error message 6: **Access is denied**.

This script works great with HP DC7900 and other HP that we have. I'm Local Administrator and I'm trying with Windows 7 64-bit.

Can someone please help me? Why do I get Access Denied?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is typically caused by 2 things:

1:  Your BIOS may have a password on it.  If so, [here is a BIOS password cracker for HP](http://code.google.com/intl/de/query/#q=hp-bios-password-cracker)  that may be helpful if you cannot locate the password.

2: Ensure you are running your script as an administrator.  If UAC is not disabled then Windows may not be launching the script as an administrator.  Try running your script from an elevated command prompt. (Click start, type "CMD" in the search area, right click, and select Run as Administrator).  By launching it from an elevated command prompt, you should avoid any Windows permission issues.